# What is an AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am looking at the documentation for Firebase Auth in order to get my native iOS app's authentication to work properly. I am having some trouble logging out of my application (the signed in user is still present in the auth() instance) and I have come across this code as a possible solution to why I can't sign out, but I don't understand the purpose of fit.

What is a AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle? Is it to help you pass the user among different view controllers or is it to sign the user out?

[image: Adding a handler]

`handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
  // ...
}`

[image: Removing a handler]
`Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle!)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you attach a handler with `Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeHandler` your completion handler will get called whenever the user's authentication state changes.

The most common case of this is when the application starts. Authenticating the user requires that the Firebase SDK calls to the Firebase servers to validate the user's credentials. This may take some time, so instead of blocking your application code (which would lead to a bad user experience), your code is allowed to continue, and Firebase handles this client-to-server call in the background. Then when the call completes it calls your auth state handler with the update authentication state for the user.

You can always call `Auth.auth().currentUser` to get the current authentication state of the user. But if you do this at application startup, the call to the server likely hasn't completed yet, and you'll get `nil` back, since there isn't an authenticated user. This *may* be exactly what you want (for example: to display the authentication state), but sometimes you'll actually want to wait until the authentication has completed (for example: if you want to navigate to a different screen where you allow the user to enter their credentials). In the latter case you'll want to use `Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeHandler` to wait for the authentication to complete, to ensure you only navigate to the next screen once you're sure the state is up to date.

Comment: Super helpful! So, correct me if I'm wrong. The following code: `handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
  // ...
}` would allow me to both check to see if my user just logged in OR logged out. And I can check that by seeing if user == nil? Also, why do I have to remove the handle once the view disappears? Doesn't it do that by itself, or does it not?

Comment: Yup, any log in/log out would trigger the callback and allow you to respond. Also see the example in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user. You have to remove them because otherwise they will keep getting called, and you'll likely end up with exceptions due to their view no longer being around.